# Why mongodb suggests to reduce tcp_keepalive_time

Tags: linux, mongodb, connection

Mongodb [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#does-tcp-keepalive-time-affect-mongodb-deployments) suggests to reduce tcp keepalive time for better performance:

> If you experience socket errors between clients and servers or between members of a sharded cluster or replica set that do not have other reasonable causes, check the TCP keepalive value (for example, the tcp_keepalive_time value on Linux systems). A common keepalive period is 7200 seconds (2 hours); however, different distributions and macOS may have different settings.

However it does not explain why this will help, how it improves performance. From my (limited)understanding, connections created by mongo shards and replicas will have their own keep alive time, which might be way shorter than linux global keep-alive values. so Mongo might break the connection as par it's config and creating new connection should ideally not take too much time.

How will it improve performance by reducing linux tcp keep alive setting?

Answer (score 1):

I thank the shorter keepalive setting on DB side or client side will keep less total connections but with higher percentage of active connections between server-client or server-server, also less connections (pool) will use less resource on server and client side.